# Jmeter simulate users sending multiple HTTP requests

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

I have five different HTTP requests I require each thread to make. All five requests need to be made by the same thread in a given order, and ideally I'd like to set an average time between each request.

How can I do this in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By default JMeter threads (virtual users) execute [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down so you basically can define the execution order by manipulating the order of Samplers under the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image]
2. If you want to introduce a fixed delay between requests add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) at the same level as the requests

   [image]

   above configuration will result in adding a 5 seconds delay **before** each request. Also delay doesn't have to be fixed, you can use i.e. [Uniform Random Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer) or [Gaussian Random Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Gaussian_Random_Timer) to closer simulate real users behavior as different users act at different speed therefore have different "think times". Check out [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) article for more information on the Timers concept and detailed information on each and every timer available in JMeter.